# Using pstool with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, psfrag

I am trying to use psfrag in conjunction with pstool an LuaLaTeX to replace a tag in an .eps plot generated with gnuplot. I'm not sure if pstool is generally working with LuaLaTeX, however, the processing of the .eps results in an compilation error because pstool seems to call pdfLaTeX instead:

```
An error occured processing graphic:
`./fig.eps'
Check the log file for compilation errors: `./fig-pstool.log'
```

And in the fig-pstool.log:

```
Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{pstool}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \psfragfig*{fig}{\psfrag{SL2}[Br]{$\int_{-1}^1 \rho dh$}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with pdfLaTeX or omitting fontspec works fine.

A sample file for `fig.eps` can be found at [Github](https://github.com/wrtc90/misc).

Comment: Are you sure, that you can compile your code with `pdfLaTeX` without any changes? Compiling with `pdfLaTeX` should throw an error when loading `polyglossia` or `fontspec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge `psfrag`/`pstool` is indeed calling `pdfLaTeX` to do the ps-magic. The problem why your code is not working is the fact that neither `polyglossia` (as it internally loads `fontspec`) nor `fontspec` are working with `pdfLaTeX`.

To still be able to use `LuaLaTeX` and those packages in combination with `psfrag`/`pstool` you can utilise the `iftex` package. Among many others, this package provides a conditional for checking which compiler is processing the `tex` file.

If you put `polyglossia` and `fontspec` in a `\ifLuaTeX` branch, everything should work nicely (Except for `fontspec`s font substitution in the `psfrag` commands).

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi
\ifPDFTeX
  % Define fonts for pdfLaTeX here
\fi

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstool}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \psfragfig*{fig}{\psfrag{SL2}[Bl]{$\int_{-1}^1 \rho dh$}}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When running `LuaLaTeX` you can in this case omit `epstopdf`. Furthermore, no need to explicitly load `psfrag` as this is done by `pstool`.

#### Edit (See comments)

The reason for the disappeared integral sign is the positioning of the replacement. The replacements can only occur in the area of the `(e)ps`, everything reaching over its borders will be cut off. To solve this issue, either replace the tag in the `eps` file or change the substitution's alignment. I changed the `[<posn>]` from `[Br]` to `[Bl]` in the above code, now everything is visible.

[image: [Bl] alignment]

Comment: I was indeed using `\usepackage{ifthen}` `\usepackage{ifluatex}` to conditionally load `fontspec` and `polyglossia`, otherwise `babel` for pdfLatex execution but probably stripped it while creating the MWE (hard to tell, have moved on to `pgfplots` long ago).
Now the weird part: Running your code with lualatex from the command line works, but the integral sign is missing in the substitution. But compiling it from within texstudio with the same command yields the first error from above in the pdf and `! LaTeX Error: File "pstool.sty"not found.`in `fig-pstool.log`.

Comment: Let's not focus on these texstudio-only errors, these seem to be unrelated configuration problems. I'll provide `fig.eps` above and maybe we'll fix the integral sign not appearing?

Comment: @Christoph90 Is it possible, that TeXstudio is calling a compiler of another distribution? (Reagrding the `"pstool.sty"not found` error)

Comment: @Christoph90 Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Working fine now from the command line! I dug around my old files from 2014 but could not find a logfile to check the compiler invocations to verify what my original mistake was. Anyway, for the present errors I get from within TeXstudio, I don't think it's another distribution since I only have tl2017 installed and call lualatex with absolute path from TeXstudio and the command line...